# Google Play Services loops my App

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

Precondition:
Don't keep activites -> Enabled

I am using the Google Drive SDK. While in the logging process you select the account to which you want to connect, then the Google Play Services show a Dialog where the user must accept the permissions required by the app. While this dialog is open I can se in the log that the onCreate() onResume() and then onPause() methods of the main activities are being called in a loop. Is this a bug of Google Play Services or coudl I be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because when you call the `AccountManager`, whis spawns its own activity, and hence the `onPause()` in your activity is called, and `onResume()` when the user has selected an account. You can bypass this by only calling the AccountManager if no account has been selected.